# The difference between Scala type bound and generalized type constraints

Tags: scala

Is there any sufficient difference between constraints of two method at the trait Foo?

```
trait Foo[A] {
    def barWithTypeBound[B <: A]: B

    def barWithGeneralizedTypeConstraint[B](implicit ev: B <:< A): B
  }
```

Comment: Sufficient for what? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are two ways to constrain type B. I do not understand the consequences of the choice. Are they equal? Or exists a situation where they are not interchangeable?

Comment: Of course there are situations where they are not interchangeable, but without knowing what you are trying to do it is not possible to say whether those differences are relevant. If you are just asking someone to explain how Scala works then this isn't the right forum for that.

Comment: https://blog.bruchez.name/posts/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala/#question-1-cant-we-just-use-type-bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to produce an evidence at call site than provide the evidence through all intermediate layers, e.g.

```
trait Flattenable[F[_]] {

  def flatten[A](ffa: F[F[A]]): F[A]
}

extension [F[_], A](fa: F[A])
  def flatten[B](using A <:< F[B], F: Flattenable[F]): F[B] =
    F.flatten(fa)
```

To implement this extension without `<:<` I would have to change the definition of fa:

```
extension [F[_], A](fa: F[F[A]])
  def flatten[B](using F: Flattenable[F]): F[B] =
    F.flatten(fa)
```

which is possible here but not in every case. Another example would be something like:

```
class Wrapper[A](value: A):

  def get: A = value

  def isNatural(using: A <:< Int): Boolean = value >= 0

  def isTrue(using A <:< Boolean): Boolean = value
```

which allows caller to call the method only of `A` is of particular type. (But again, you could solve these with specialized extension methods and normal constraints). I was able to define parametric type in one place, and slap an additional constraint on it later on. If I would need that constrain from the start, I would just use a type bound.

Usually, there is no need to make some method (or implicit, or given) available or not based on the type. And it only proves that some particular case is true, so it wouldn't work well with co- and contravatiance. And, it requires you to create a dummy object. So with exception of a few cases where such "hack" is useful normal constrains are preferred.

In your example there is no difference between the 2 methods, except the second one would have to pass and additional object as a parameter.

Comment: Why use Scala 3 syntax in an answer to a question in Scala 2 syntax and without the `scala3` tag?

Comment: Because it is still the same language, answers with Scala 2 will be outdated pretty fast, and Scala 2 implemented extension methods and implicits in a way that makes things harder to reason. I see no need to get back to 2 unless explicitly required.

Comment: That's odd, because I tried compiling that code in Scala 2 and it didn't work. And with major libraries not even making it to 2.13, Scala 2 is very definitely the dominant version of Scala and will be for a long time.